# how to use runningSum in AWS QuickSight

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I am encountering the following error when running clearting a calculated field: runningSum(sum(user_count),[date_created ASC],[]) to get the running total of created [image: quick]

I have tried to add the '{}' on the fields, and no luck.
How can I get this calculated field to work and give me the running totals

Answer (score 4):

I was able to find an answer to this. I did it the following way:

```
runningSum(sum({count}), [truncDate("MM",{creationdate}) ASC], [{region}])
```

and I found an interesting catch.... whenever I tried adding **at the moment that I'm configuring the data source, it'd fail**.

So I went through and **added the calculated field on the area where I can edit the visuals** - and there it worked.

Here's my end result

[image]

Hope it works for you.